# Why doesn't the type parameter of Function.identity() get inferred here? (Java 17)

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, java-stream

I'm expecting that the following code will produce a map where one value is the largest integer in the list greater than the given threshold, and the other value is the largest integer in the list less than the given threshold.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Integer> list = List.of(1, 2, 3, 5, 6);

    Map<Boolean, Integer> map = largestGreaterAndLessThan(list, 4);

    System.out.println(map);
}

private static Map<Boolean, Integer> largestGreaterAndLessThan(List<Integer> list, int threshold) {
    return list.stream()
               .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x > threshold, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity()))));
}
```

However the code does not compile, instead producing the following error:

```
error: no suitable method found for toMap((x)->x > threshold,Function<Object,Object>,BinaryOperator<T#1>)                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x > threshold, Function.identity(), BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Function.identity()))));
```

By changing `Function.identity()` in both places to the lambda `x -> x`, or by changing `Function.identity()` to `Function.<Integer>identity()` in just one place, the code compiles and runs properly. My question is, why does the type variable `Integer` of `Function.identity()` not get inferred here? I should also note that IntelliJ did not catch this error in the code editor, instead telling me that the type variable fed to `Function.identity()` was unnecessary. Thanks

Comment: Same behaviour in 20. Another 'fix' is `Collectors.<Integer,Boolean,Integer>toMap(`.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but you can simplify the merge function to: `BinaryOperator.maxBy(Integer::compare)`. With this simplification, Java is able to figure the types out.

Comment: Your code works fine with Eclipse, however, I don’t get why you’re making things so complicated. Just use `.collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x>threshold, Function.identity(), Math::max))`. Things works smooth, whether you use ecj or javac.